# Why using error code (such as -1) is not efficient than using exception?

Tags: java, exception

In the JLS8, chapter "Exceptions" ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html)), I saw that:

> Explicit use of throw statements provides an alternative to the
>   old-fashioned style of handling error conditions by returning funny
>   values, such as the integer value -1 where a negative value would not
>   normally be expected. Experience shows that too often such funny
>   values are ignored or not checked for by callers, leading to programs
>   that are not robust, exhibit undesirable behavior, or both.

Actually, I'm not clear about 2 issues following:

(1) "such as the integer value -1 where a negative value would not normally be expected", why "a negative value would not normally be expected"? Follow my knowledge, we often use return value "-1" for an error, abnormal event,... or something "not good".

(2) "Experience shows that too often such funny values are ignored or not checked for by callers, leading to programs that are not robust, exhibit undesirable behavior, or both.". What "funny values are ignored or not checked for by callers, leading to programs that are not robust, exhibit undesirable behavior, or both" means? I don't understant this issue...Please help me to clarify and (if yes) give me an example to demonstrate

Thank you so much

Comment: Your title mentions efficiency but your question does not.  In fact the use of Exceptions is not efficient

Comment: Using an Exception **forces** the coder to do something about the error, simply returning a negative number allows the code to continue.  Compare `int age = enterYourAge ();` returning `-1` rather than `enterYourAge` throwing an Exception if bad input is entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please help me to clarify and (if yes) give me an example to demonstrate:

For example `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)` returns `null` if it cannot find the resource, rather than throwing an exception.  This is clearly documented in the javadocs.

However, lots of people **don't read the documentation**, and don't check the result of a `getResourceAsStream` call.  As a result, when the resource is missing, they *use* the `null` and get an unexpected `NullPointerException`.

Another common example is `ServletRequest.getParameter(String)`.

If you analysed the NPE Q's on StackOverflow, you would find that a significant number of them are caused by people not checking the results of the above two methods.  (If you don't believe me, the raw questions are available for you to analyse!)

> Why using error code (such as -1) is not efficient than using exception?

The text you quoted doesn't say that.  And it is probably not true.  In fact, the using an error code is (classically) more efficient in many cases.  However, with recent JIT compiler improvements, the overheads of exceptions and exception handling have been *significantly* reduced for typical use-cases.

---

Summary:

1. People are lazy.  But you knew that!
2. People are careless.  But you knew that!
3. APIs that require people to check returned values are less robust than those that throw (checked) exceptions ... because people write code that doesn't check return codes.  Why?  Because people are lazy, careless or both!

Admittedly, there are pragmatic reasons not to throw exceptions.  However it is a trade-off of robustness vs efficiency vs forcing the programmer to deal with checked exceptions.

The text you quoted is not trying to tell you use exceptions always.  Rather it is explaining the reasons that exceptions are part of the Java language.

You may disagree, but ... frankly ... it is not a topic that is worth debating.  Exceptions (checked / unchecked, etc) are so hard-baked into the Java language that it would be impossible to change.

Comment: Hi @Stephen C, if before I return the error code (e.g -1), I checked the condition like if (_myString_=="") {return -1}...So, in this case, it my funny value is checked? or ignored?

Comment: You are missing the point.  The return code is checked (or not) in the code that *calls* this method.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen C, and may I epitomize your idea
1. When we use return code (=error code, like -1,...) to mark something "not good" in our program => ok, it's seem good. But, when we ignore it (or we do not check it) => may be we are lazy or careless (follow your idea), the program can perform not good (=not robust or exhibit undesirable behavior,...)..So, using the error code seems to be not a good choice.
2. Thus, we use "exception" (and "exception handling") to resolve this problem because it guarantee the "consistency" as well as "portability" and "robustness".

Comment: That is approximately what I mean.  Though I never used the word "consistency", and I don't know what you mean by it.

Answer (score 2):

A common example is: people *not* checking the contents of a string, but blindly calling `indexOf()` - and not taking into account that the "thing searched for" isn't in that string, so the returned result is -1.

At least when using *checked* exception the programmer *must* do something about a potential exception thrown from some code that his code is using. For return values, you can completely ignore them - just a bit easier therefore.

On the other hand, many people argue that the idea of *checked* exception didn't live up to its promise - and are therefore advocating the usage of unchecked exceptions. Or alternatively, as companies such as google propose: the usage of more sophisticated "return value classes".

Long story short:

- by the nature of the language exceptions should be seen as the *primary* mean to communicate *severe* **exceptional** conditions
- but that doesn't mean that using numeric return codes is not possible or completely discouraged.

Comment: Of course, we now have `Optional` as an alternative to exceptions or special values like -1, assuming there is only one possible "special" return.

Comment: @ajb `Optional` isn't an alternative to exceptions, it's an alternative to returning null (which of course can considered a special value, but not in a particularly exceptional sense).

Comment: @Kayaman I think it's alternative to returning other special values.  In particular, `indexOf()` was mentioned in the answer, and if `Optional` had been around, it would have been better for this to return an `Optional<Integer>` instead of an integer with a special value -1 to indicate "not found" which is error-prone.  But yes, it's not really equivalent to an exception.

Comment: Hi @GhostCat, if before I return the error code (e.g -1), I checked the condition like if (_myString_=="") {return -1}...So, in this case, it my funny value is checked? or ignored?

Comment: We are talking about the **client** that receives the -1 ?!  I dont get your question.

Answer (score 1):

> (1) "such as the integer value -1 where a negative value would not normally be expected", why "a negative value would not normally be expected"?

It is a proven fact (see below) that people don't always check return values.

> Follow my knowledge, we often use return value "-1" for an error, abnormal event,... or something "not good".

True. And exceptions provide an alternative.

> What "funny values are ignored or not checked for by callers

'Funny values' such as -1. There are examples posted here every hour of every day.

> leading to programs that are not robust, exhibit undesirable behavior, or both" means?

It means that programs that ignore 'funny values' aren't robust or exhibit undesirable behaviour ... and give rise to trivial questions on this site.

> I don't understand this issue...Please help me to clarify and (if yes) give me an example to demonstrate.

Try [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ignoring+end+of+stream) for hundreds of examples.

Answer (score 0):

When a method return an `int`, the caller have to check if it is an error code. But if here is no expected range of returned value, how could you specify an error signal value?

Let us say what "error code" should a `parseInt` method return?

And if the caller "forgets" to check the returned value, the error could go unnoticed.

However if an exception is declared, the caller must check and handle it, by `catch`ing it or declaring i in `throws`...